# How could I build a dictionary in C# from a CSV file where the keys are in one column and the values in other?

Tags: c#, dictionary, readfile

I have an excel file (separated with with commas) two columns, `City` and `Country`. 
Column A has countries and column B has cities. Each row therefore has a country and a city located in this country.

```
City  Country 

Madrid    Spain    

Barcelona Spain    

Paris     France   

Valencia  Spain    

Rome      Italy    

Marseille  France   

Florence   Italy
```

I am wondering a way to read this excel in C# in a Dictionary> type where the key will be my country and the values the city, so after reading it I will have the following:

```
{
 "Spain":  ["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Valencia"], 
 "France": ["Paris", "Marseille"], 
 "Italy":  ["Rome", "Florence"]
}
```

What I have tried so far is creating this class:

```
class ReadCountryCityFile
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> countrycitydict{ get; }
    // constructor
    public ReadCountryCityFile()
    {
        countrycitydict= new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ReadFile(string path)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            List<string> listcountry = new List<string>();
            List<string> listcity = new List<string>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line != "Country;City")
                    {
                        List<string> citieslist = new List<string>();
                        var values = line.Split(';');
                        citieslist .Add(values[0]);
                        string country= values[1];
                        countrycitydict[intents] = citieslist ;
                    }
                }
                return countrycitydict;
        }
   }
```

But `countrydict` is not as expected. How could I do it?

How could I solved it if intead of

```
City Country

Madrid Spain
```

I had

```
City   Country

Madrid    Spain
Valencia
```

Comment: What is `intentutterance`? Looks like you need to clean up your example a bit :).

Comment: Also please clarify if the cities are in the first column and the countries in the second. Your example put the country first and the cities last, but your code does the reverse

Comment: Fixed! Thank you

Comment: I suspect you might actually want a Lookup rather than a Dictionary. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing that you use a *simple* CSV (with no quotations) you can try *Linq*:

```
 Dictionary<string, string[]> result = File
   .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.csv")
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // To be on the safe side
   .Skip(1)  // If we want to skip the header (the very 1st line)
   .Select(line => line.Split(';')) //TODO: put the right separator here
   .GroupBy(items => items[0].Trim(), 
            items => items[1])
   .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                 chunk => chunk.ToArray());
```

**Edit:** If you want (see comments below) `Dictionary<string, string>` (not `Dictionary<string, string[]>`) e.g. you want

```
   ...
  {"Spain",  "Madrid\r\nBarcelona\r\nValencia"}, 
   ...
```

instead of 
       ...
      {"Spain",  ["Madrid", "Barcelona", "Valencia"]}
       ...

you can modify the last `.ToDictionary` into:

```
   .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                 chunk => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, chunk));
```

Comment: What should chunk be?

Comment: @Marisa that line should be `.ToDictionary(chunk=>chunk.Key, chunk=>chunk.ToArray())`

Comment: @Marisa: I'm sorry for the typo; it should be two lamdas: `chunk => chunk.Key` for dictionariy's key and `chunk => chunk.ToArray()` for value

Comment: How should I do if instead of Madrid for the first value I had Madrid *break line* Valencia? @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 0):

While you loop over your input try to check if your dictionary has alredy the key inserted. If not insert it and then add the value at the key

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> countrycitydict{ get; }

public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ReadFile(string path)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != "Country;City")
            {
                var values = line.Split(';');

                // Try to get the entry for the current country
                if(!countrycitydict.TryGetValue(values[0], out List<string> v))
                {
                    // If not found build an entry for the country
                    List<string> cities = new List<string>()
                    countrycitydict.Add(values[0], cities) ;
                }
                // Now you can safely add the city
                countrycitydict[values[0]].Add(values[1]);
            }
       }
       return countrycitydict;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could also just use the `ContainsKey` method of the dictionary.